Attach follower DB on existing DB on Kusto
Does the attachment of a database require this same DB to be created beforehand or not exactly? The attachment process “creates” DB on the fly?
I read the documentation, but that information is not very clear.
The thing is, I am creating a database in one instance and attaching the follower in another instance (because the leader is there).

In order for a database to be attached to a (follower) cluster, it must exist on the leader cluster.
You can't attach a database that does not exist, i.e. Hasn't been created yet.
The process of attaching a database does not create a new database, and you are not required to create a database with the same name on the follower, prior to attaching the database.

We have a leader cluster called ClusterA and a follower cluster called ClusterB right? Leader has a database called DemoDB, in order to attach this DB to the follower cluster, do I need to create this database in the follower cluster (with same name for example) first or not?

Following this documentation Use follower database feature to attach databases in Azure Data Explorer.
So my feeling is that we don’t need to create a database on the follower cluster beforehand so that a leader cluster can attach.
